# Can I execute an application built with Quickly (python - pygtk) on MS Windows?

Tags: windows, application-development, python, quickly, pygtk

I am working with QUICKLY, using Python and PyGtk. I know there is an option for packaging; so I can create a .DEB file. This is for Ubuntu.

I was reading about PyGTK and it seems that PyGtk runs on MS Windows too. So, can I execute an app built with Quickly on MS Windows? If so, how? Which is the file (.py) that I have to execute on MS Windows? (a Quickly project has many .py files)

Thanks.

Ariel

Comment: I found out that Quickly is not using PyGtk any more. Now, on Ubuntu 12.04, it is using PyGObject instead (for using GTK3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, like I said Quickly on Ubuntu 12.04 uses PyGObject (GTK3) instead of PyGTK (GTK2). There is a MS Windows version of PyGObject too, but I think that QUICKLY uses Linux commands to create the final structure of Python files. This structure is built when the developer wants to test the program ("quckly run program-name"), or when he wants to create a DEB package.

On the other hand, in some parts of some Python files, paths are specified using Linux directories ("opt", for example). So, Quickly files can't be used on MS Windows, at least not directly.

Ariel